# Angular2 // Why is DependencyInjection with Generics only working in Components?

Tags: generics, dependency-injection, typescript, angular

I have a service using generics that I would like to inject into another service like this

```
export class RestoreService<T>
```

Injection works in components like this

```
constructor(private restoreService: RestoreService<Hero>) {}
```

If I try to inject the same service into a non Component class I get an Exception saying "Cannot resolve all parameters for OtherService(?). Make sure they all have valid type or annotations."

Here is a sample sample based on the hierarchical injection sample by angular.io
http://plnkr.co/edit/wkj838xacI3cbOvz3qTs?p=preview

I also noticed that injecting multiple instances of RestoreService with different Ts results only in one instance being created. So I wonder if working with generic classes is a recommended pattern at all.

Comment: Generics have nothing to do with Injection, If you want Angular to inject something to your service, he must know about it and in order for him to know about it is by adding an annotation to it, simply add `@Injectable` to the Service you want to inject something to, or add `@Inject` right next to the property you want to inject

Comment: That's right but still only one instance of the RestoreService is created when I try to inject RestoreService<Hero> and RestoreService<AntiHero>. I expected to get two instances here.

Comment: Generics don't define how instances are created, they have nothing to do with Dependency Injection. If you want to define how they get instanced you need to create a provider: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/Provider-class.html

Answer (score 2):

Ensure you have all dependencies registered as providers.
Adding for example `RestoreService, OtherService` to the providers to

```
bootstrap(HeroesListComponent, [HeroesService, RestoreService, OtherService])
```

fixes the error.

I didn't fully investigate your example but you have `RestoreService` and `OtherService` added to `providers:` in `hero-editor.components.ts`, which makes them known there but it doesn't make them known to the whole application.

Note: If you want to have only one instance of the service in your application (singleton) only add it on one place - usually `bootstrap(...)`.
If you want DI to create a new instance for each component, add it to the components providers.